# Question on geometric distribution

Tags: probability

**Suppose that the probability for an applicant to get a job offer after an
interview is 0.01. An applicant plans to keep trying out for more interviews
until she gets offered. Assume outcomes of interviews are independent.
What is the probability she will need to attend more than 2 interviews?**

*My Solution :*

p=.01

Let X denote the number of interviews to be attended.

so, Pr(X>=3)=(1-.01)^2=.98

This question is off a textbook and the given answer is 0.81. Could someone please advice on the correct solution, and thanks

Comment: The data 0.01 is probably 0.1.

Comment: Yeah that seems to work. Must be misprinted. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data 0.01 is probably 0.1.